# C and dynamic structure element access

Tags: c, pointers, struct, element, structure

I have this complicated structure thingie:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} SUB;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    SUB *z;
} STRUCT;

#define NUM  5

int main(void)
{
    STRUCT *example;
    int i;

    example = malloc(sizeof(STRUCT));

    example->z = malloc(NUM * sizeof(SUB));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
        /* how do I access variable in certain struct of array of z's */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`example` is dynamically allocated structure and `z` inside the `example` is dynamically allocated array of `SUB` structures.

How do I access certain variable in certain element of structure `z`?

I have been trying something like this: **`example->z[i].x`** but it doesnt seem to work.

At the moment I am using this shabby looking workaraound:

```
SUB *ptr = example->z;
int i;

for(i = 0; i < amount_of_z_structs; ++i) {
    /* do something with  'ptr->x' and 'ptr->y' */
    ptr += sizeof(SUB);
}
```

Comment: After debugging it looks like the shorter version is incrementing only 8 bytes instead of correct 64 bytes.

Comment: I think that you haven't told us the whole story. **If** you have properly allocated memory for both `example` and `example->z`, then `example->z[i].x` is a perfectly valid expression.

Comment: Everything is happening like in the example (except actual code has error checking). I can't see any problems with the code. And why is the workaround working but not the shorter version.

Comment: Okay, before anyone can do anything else useful for you, you need to post the shortest possible program that "doesn't work" using `example->z[i].x`, and tell us precisely how it doesn't work. We've posted working code based on yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't where you say it is. Your code as posted gives a compile error:

```
error: request for member ‘z’ in something not a structure or union
```

at the line

```
example.z = malloc(sizeof(STRUCT));
```

because you meant to write `example->z`, since `example` is a pointer to `STRUCT`, not a `STRUCT`.

From there on, you can access `example->z[i].x` exactly as you said. That syntax has always been fine.

For example:

```
/* your declarations here */

example = malloc(sizeof(STRUCT));
example->z = malloc(NUM * sizeof(SUB));

for(i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
    example->z[i].x = i;
    example->z[i].y = -i;
    printf("%d %d\n", example->z[i].x, example->z[i].y);
}

/* output:
0 0
1 -1
2 -2
3 -3
4 -4
*/
```

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I misswrote it in the example. My actual program is not giving any compiling errors even with -Wall option enable. Also valgrind gives me a clear papers.

Comment: @Xrm: And my program gives *exactly* the output I'd expect. I don't know what your problem is - it's not in here.

Comment: I compiled that with my windows Dev-C++ IDE and its printing rubbish. When I compiled the same code on my unix box with `GCC 4.4`, it works. Could it be possible that the old GCC version bundled with Dev-C++ is somehow broken.

Comment: @XrM: That's... interesting. This code is so basic I have a hard time seeing what could go wrong. Try checking the values of `example` and `example->z` - if `malloc` somehow failed they should be `NULL`.

Comment: Error checking is on place in actual code. No problems there. I must admit that I have very old version of Dev-C++ installed on my laptop. This might some kind of libc implementation error too. I updated to Code::Blocks with GCC 4.x and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you have pointers pointing to pointers you often end up running into precedence issues. I can't recall if this is one, but you might try `(example->b)[i].x`.

Comment: Same as `example->z[i].x`. Note: `b` changed to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int my_x = example[3].z[2].x;
```

- The above code will first access the example[3] (the fourth element of the example array).
- Once you get that particular element, its contents can be automatically access in the same way as you do with normal objects.
- You then access z[2] from that element. Note that, `example[3]` is an element, so you could use a `.` to access its members; if its an array, you can access it as an array.
- So till now, `example[3].z[2]` is **one** element of the SUB array inside **one** element of the `example` array.
- Now you can simply access the member `x` using the way shown above.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} SUB;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    SUB *z;
} STRUCT;

STRUCT *example;

int main() {
    example = malloc(sizeof(STRUCT)*10); //array of 10;
    int i=0,j=0;
    for (;i<10;i++){
        example[i].a = i;
        example[i].z = malloc(sizeof(SUB)*5);
        for (j=0; j<5; j++)
            example[i].z[j].x = example[i].z[j].y = j;
    }
    //access example[3] and access z[2] inside it. And finally access 'x'
    int my_x = example[3].z[2].x;
    printf("%d",my_x);

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d |\n",example[i].a);
        //example[i].z = malloc(sizeof(SUB)*5);
        for (j=0; j<5; j++)
            printf("%d %d\n",example[i].z[j].x,example[i].z[j].y);
        free(example[i].z);
    }
    free(example);
}
```

Comment: Not a particularly useful answer. If everything has been allocated to make this work, `example->z[2].x` would work too, being the same as `example[0].z[2].x`.

Comment: I never denied what you said. He isnt wrong with the syntax. Only with the logical way. :-)

Comment: @Thrustmaster: There's not necessarily anything wrong with the logic either. Pointers don't always point to arrays - they could be single objects too.

Comment: I didnt deny this either. I dont get your point. Please explain.

Comment: My point is that the bulk of your answer is suggesting that the OP access this variable as an array, when it actually isn't. It doesn't address whatever the real problem is.

Comment: Ohh, yes! Now I get it. I thought the OP has the `example` as an array. Sorry, my bad. :(
Thanks for your comment though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second `malloc` is wrong; `example` is a pointer so this:

```
example.z = malloc(NUM * sizeof(SUB));
```

should be this:

```
example->z = malloc(NUM * sizeof(SUB));
```

Then in your loop you can say things like this:

```
example->z[i].x = i;
example->z[i].y = i;
```

You'll also want to have this near the top of your file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Already fixed `.` -> `->`. 2. I know that that `stdlib.h` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'shabby workaround', you wrote:

```
SUB *ptr = example->z;
int i;

for(i = 0; i < amount_of_z_structs; ++i) {
    /* do something with  'ptr->x' and 'ptr->y' */
    ptr += sizeof(SUB);
}
```

The problem here is that C scales pointers by the size of the object pointed to, so when you add 1 to a `SUB` pointer, the value is advanced by `sizeof(SUB)`.  So, you simply need:

```
SUB *ptr = example->z;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
    ptr->x = ptr->y = 0;
    ptr++;
}
```

Of course, as others have said, you can also do (assuming C99):

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
    example->z[i].x = example->z[i].y = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define NUM 5

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}SUB;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    SUB* z;
}STRUCT;

void main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    printf("Sample problem..\n\n");

    STRUCT* example;
    int i;

    example = (STRUCT*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT));
    example->z = (SUB*)malloc(NUM * sizeof(SUB));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        example->z[i].x = i +1;
        example->z[i].y = (example->z[i].x)+1;
        printf("i = %d: x:%d y:%d\n", i, example->z[i].x, example->z[i].y);
    }
}
```